# Error: Native RNSkia Module cannot be found! Make sure you correctly installed native dependencies and rebuilt your app., js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, skia

Hello everyone im trying to use RNSkia with expo go. After doing some research I found out its integrated now with expo-go.
Also cant find anything in the docs for extra configuration

Im using:

- "expo": "~48.0.6",
- "@shopify/react-native-skia": "0.1.172",
- "react-native": "0.71.8",

ERROR : Native RNSkia Module cannot be found! Make sure you correctly installed native dependencies and rebuilt your app., js engine: hermes
ERROR Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called., js engine: hermes